# How to append to an existing sheet and empty a dataFrame for new data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This might be a noob question but how can I append to a sheet instead of overwriting the existing data. Then how can I empty a dataFrame so it can be populated wit new data.

Basically I am reading in a file and populating a dataFrame writing to a sheet then emptying the dataFrame so it may be empty to read in new data.

I am stuck at empting the dataFrame:

```
avgs = avgs.drop(['Period start','Period end','zone','usid','site id','rank','Total LCQI Impact','LTE BLOCK Impact','LTE DROP Impact','LTE TPUT Impact','engineer notes'],axis=1)
```

And appending to the sheet.

```
 avgs.to_excel("pandas_out.xlsx",merge_cells=False) ## need to append to file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using `avgs = pd.DataFrame()` to empty existing dataframe. In case of you want to preserve column names, you can try `avgs = pd.DataFrame(columns=avgs.columns)` instead.

Regarding dataframe append, there are many ways to do it. But you have to proceed it along following step. First `pd.read_excel()`, then append something, finally `df.to_excel()` again. About ways to append, Please refer to [pd.concat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), [pd.Series.append()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.append.html), [pd.DataFrame.append()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed.